# What does it mean to find elements in $S_9$ that are "not cycles"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I came across this wording in the following question. Some clarification on what this means and how to approach this problem would be helpful. Thanks!

[image: Problem]

Comment: in $S_9$, the permutation $(1,2,3,4)$ is a cycle but $(1,2,3,4)(5,6,7,8)$ is not.

Comment: what is the cardinality of a permutation?

Comment: @OfirSchnabel it is not cardinality, that's order as group element, that is minimal $n > 0$ such that $x^n = e$, where $e$ is group identity (identity permutation in this case).

Comment: @lisyarus , Yes I see it in the answer below. I know what an order of an element $g$ of a group is, I think it is more common to denote it by $\circ (g)$.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel well, I've seen both notations quite often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation  $|\mu|$ means the *order* of $\mu$ in $S_9$.

*Hint:*

- Every permutation is a product of disjoint cycles
- The order of a product of disjoint cycles is the lcm of their orders

*Solution*:

> $\mu = (1234)(56)$ has order $4$ but is not a cycle. Other examples are  $(1234)(5678)$ and $(1234)(56)(78)$.  As for $\omega$, an element of order $5$ must be a product of disjoint cycles of order $5$, but in $S_9$ there are no two disjoint cycles of order $5$ because that would required at least $10$ objects to permute.

Comment: I suspected this would be the approach (looking at the orders). I'm still confused about the wording though. Aren't all elements in $S_n$ composed of cycles?

Comment: @Akyidrian, *composed* yes, but not of a single cycle, e.g. $(12)(34)$ is not a cycle.

Comment: So with $w$, only single cycles are possible. Whereas with $\mu$ you could have (1234)(56) or (1234)(5678) for example (i.e. cycles with length 4 and 2, or 4 and 4). Does this sound right?

Comment: Sorry to be nit-picky, so(1234)(5678) is valid for $\mu$?

Comment: Thanks alot! You helped big time!